# python numpy array search by key

Tags: python, numpy

I have created numpy zeros array as like below

```
data = np.zeros(8, dtype={'names':('name', 'token', 'price'),
              'formats':('U10', 'i8', 'f8')})
```

and assigned value in for loop

```
for n,a in enumerate(data):
    data[n]['token'] = sList[n].token
    data[n]['name'] = sList[n].name
    data[n]['price'] = sList[n].price
```

now I want to search data array with the key like where

```
d = np.where(data[['name']] == 'Ram')
```

Comment: You should consider using `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
data = np.array([('Ram', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.),
           ('Ram', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.)],
           dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('token', '<i8'), ('price', '<f8')])
```

---

Look at the difference between when you index using `'name'` vs. `['name']`:

```
>>> data['name']
array(['Ram', '', '', '', 'Ram', '', '', ''], dtype='<U10')

>>> data[['name']]
array([('Ram',), ('',), ('',), ('',), ('Ram',), ('',), ('',), ('',)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U10')])
```

This distinction is clearly defined in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html#indexing-structured-arrays)

> **Accessing Individual Fields**
>
> Individual fields of a structured array
>   may be accessed and modified by indexing the array with the field
>   name.
>
> **Accessing Multiple Fields**
>
> One can index and assign to a structured array with a multi-field index, where the index is a list of field names.

Since you want to compare a string with the values of a single field, you must access this using only the field name:

```
>>> np.where(data['name'] == 'Ram')
(array([0, 4], dtype=int64),)
```